# Set (Spring) bean property programmatically

Tags: java, cxf

I am currently trying to setup Apache CXF with OAuth authentication. I am at the point that the `OAuthDataProvider` needs to start providing Client information. In the [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-WritingOAuthDataProvider) is stated that you can configure the `dataProvider` with the following xml;

```xml
<!-- implements OAuthDataProvider -->
<bean id="oauthProvider" class="oauth.manager.OAuthManager"/>

<bean id="accessTokenService" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AccessTokenService">
  <property name="dataProvider" ref="oauthProvider"/>
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="oauthServer" address="/oauth">
   <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="accessTokenService"/>
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Now I am not using Spring, using the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet` and having a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class provide the classes/singletons and properties required.

Now the question is; Is there a way to configure this `dataProvider` property programmatically without having to use Spring? Or even in the web.xml for example?

**Edit**

I found I can solve it by extending the AccessTokenService class and doing the following.

```
class CustomAccessTokenService extends AccessTokenService {

    public CustomAccessTokenService() {
        setDataProvider(new OAuthManager());
    }
}
```

but that does not seem like a very elegant solution.

**Simplified version of Application implementation**

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
class ServiceApplication extends Application {

    private final Set<Class<?>> _classes = new HashSet<>();

    public ServiceApplication() {
        _classes.add(...)
        _classes.add(AccessTokenService.class)
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return _classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to deploy AccessTokenService as an independent JAX-RS endpoint ?

Comment: Currently it is mapped to /services/* like every other service in the project, if it is a solution to map it to a separate endpoint that would do.

Comment: I don't understand. You say you don't use Spring, but want Spring configuration anyway?

Comment: No, I don't want Spring configuration, that is what I am trying to avoid. But I currently don't have a way to access the `AccessTokenService` instance to call `setDataProvider`. Something that in the case of Spring would be handled by the bean.xml above.

Comment: Where is the token service registered in your case? You should be able to access it there.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I've added a simplified implementation of my ServiceApplication class to show you how the AccessTokenService is registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `getSingletons()` method of Application - see below:

OK, after that response, you can do this (I pulled this from a project I have, I use the methods to determine API keys to inject into my REST services):

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RESTApplication extends Application {
@Override

    private SingletonServiceObject getMySingletonService(){
        ... Do whatever to setup your singleton ...
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        L.info("Setting up REST - getSingletons()");
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        try {
            singletons.add(getMySingletonService());
            singletons.add(new GeoService());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ProjectRuntimeException("Error creating service!", e);
        }
        L.info("Finished REST - getSingletons()");
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

After seeing your edit, you can do the following:

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
AccessTokenService myBean = context.getBean(AccessTokenService.class);
myBean.setDataProvider(...whatever...);
```

Note that there is also a way to provide instances of beans from your `Application` class.  I don't remember how to do that off-hand, but either way should work.

- Pre edit answer is below *

All the XML means is `accessTokenService.setDataProvider(oauthProvider)`, so have your `Application` class call that method on the `accessTokenService` you are creating.

Comment: I am not creating the accessTokenService, that is done somewhere by JAX/CXF, I am just providing `AccessTokenService.class` in the `getClasses` method of the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`

Comment: Check out the new answer - couple of options

Comment: WebApplicationContext appears to only be available when using Spring.

Comment: OK, see my edit again - you can use `getSingletons()` instead of 
 `getClasses`